# Can the Dimension Dervish chain be use in conjunction with combat, teamwork feats?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, flanking, helping

Can I string the [Dimensional Agility](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-agility/) Feat chain (specifically, [Dimensional Savant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-savant/)) and [Precise Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-strike-combat-teamwork/) feat together? As I read it since I can flank with myself as an ally doesn't the feat bonus apply as well?

Precise Strike:

> Whenever you and an ally who also has this feat are flanking the same the creature, you deal an additional 1d6 points of precision damage with each successful melee attack. This bonus damage stacks with other sources of precision damage, such as sneak attack. This bonus damage is not multiplied on a critical hit.

Dimensional Agility:

> While using the Dimensional Dervish feat, you provide flanking from all squares you attack from. Flanking starts from the moment you make an attack until the start of your next turn. You can effectively flank with yourself and with multiple allies when using this feat.

Comment: I'm not sure if it does or doesn't but after looking online for abundant step and the dimensional dervish chain, the closest I found was people wanting to cast dimension door to do so.

Comment: I removed the Spells tag because you're not asking how a spell works; We can safely assume you have the spell or Abundant Step and understand how the *other* Dimensional Agility feats work. I also did some quality control type stuff- adding links and clarifying that the paragraphs you entered were actually quotes of the Feats in question.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

*Precise Strike* states:

> ...Whenever you and *an ally* who also has this feat are flanking the same the creature... ([d20pfsrd](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-strike-combat-teamwork/), Emphasis mine)

And the FAQ on the Paizo site says:

> You count as your own ally unless otherwise stated or if doing so would make no sense or be impossible. Thus, "your allies" almost always means the same as "you and your allies." ([Link](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9nda))

Since *Dimensional Savant* makes it possible to flank with "an ally" and does not explicitly say you can't flank with yourself, this works.

Comment: Yes, the flanking with yourself bit works, but Precise Strike clearly seems to call out for two characters with that feat flanking the same enemy. 
One character flanking an enemy doesn't seem to meet the requirement for Precise Strike - despite that enemy still being flanked by one character.

Answer (score 2):

### No, this does not work

Precise Strike says:

> Whenever *you **and** an ally* who also has this feat are flanking the same the creature, you deal an additional 1d6 points of precision damage with each successful melee attack [...]

There is no argument about whether or not you count as your own ally, but you don't count as two people. As you can see, the Precise Strike feat specifically requires both you *and* an ally.

Dimensional Savant, in its entirety, says:

> You flash into and out of reality so quickly it is impossible to tell exactly where you are at any given time.
>
> **Prerequisites**: Dimensional Agility, Dimensional Assault, Dimensional Dervish, ability to use the abundant step class feature or cast dimension door, base attack bonus +9.
>
> **Benefit**: While using the Dimensional Dervish feat, you provide flanking from all squares you attack from. Flanking starts from the moment you make an attack until the start of your next turn. You can effectively flank with yourself and with multiple allies when using this feat.

Dimensional Agility allows you to flank with yourself, but nowhere in its text does allow you to count as two people, therefore, you can't gain the benefits of that teamwork feat by flanking with yourself.